# How to target an element inside shadowRoot (user-agent) in Puppeteer

Tags: testing, jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing, stenciljs

could you please help me with targeting the concrete element in e2e test?

I´m using Jest and Puppeteer and I have this DOM structure (see in attachment below):
And I need to target the red underlined element. How would you target that element?

I tried it like this,

```
const inputContent = await page.findAll(
 'usu-date-picker >>> .sc-usu-input >>> div',
);
console.log(inputContent[1]);
```

but what I got returned was element with type node "INPUT", which I don´t understand why.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like Puppeteer. What testing/browser automation is this? If it is Puppeteer and `.findAll` is some test suite thing I'm not familiar with, I'd suggest [Puppeteer not giving accurate HTML code for page with shadow roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525115/puppeteer-not-giving-accurate-html-code-for-page-with-shadow-roots/68540701#68540701) which links over half a dozen resources on working with shadow roots.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
await page.evaluate( () => 
document.querySelector("#date-picker")
.shadowRoot.querySelector("usu-input > div > input")
.shadowRoot.querySelector("div:nth-child(2)").value
);
```

You should try the query in the devtools console to see if you are doing it right

[Example from devtools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hgnh.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn´t work like that. It throws error:  "Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')"

Comment: Is the image you shared all the code? Because if you have more shadowRoot you need to put it like in my example. And you should try the query in the devtools console to see if you are doing it right